# Excel ranking based on grouping priorities

Tags: excel

Hi everyone I have an excel question on how to rank but based first on a a ranking but then *next* on a second priority of a group. The formula is written in column 'Final_Rank' and I just hid a bunch of rows to show the clear example. Within the column Rank is just a normal rank function. I want the priority to be within Rank first, but then to add the next rank to the next item of the same group*. So if you look at Group HYP it will supersede ranked (3 and 4) and then 5 would be given to the next newest group.

I hope this is a clear explanation, thanks.

```
Group   Rank   Final_Rank_Manual   
TAM     1         1                  
HYP     2         2                  
GAB     3         5                  
HYO     4         8                  
ALO     5         9                  
HYP     7         3                  
ACO     8         12                 
IBU     9         13                 
ACO     11        14                 
ALO     18        10                 
GAB     44        6                  
IBU     53        15                 
IBU     123       16                 
GAB     167       7                  
HYP     199       4
```

Comment: I believe this will require vba as any formula would cause a circular reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an extra helper column. Assuming your table currently occupies columns A-C, with one header row, put the following in C2:

```
=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=A2,$B$2:$B$6,9999999999),1)+(B2*0.000000001)
```

You'll need to enter this as an array formula by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Copy it down throughout the whole column. This gives you the group's ranking, and it adds a tiny decimal indicating the individual values position within each group. (e.g. the 3rd "HYP" value is converted to something like 2.0000000199, because out of all the available values, the second lowest belongs to "HYP", and this specific "HYP" value is 199).

Next, enter the following in D2 and copy it down throughout the column:

```
=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$6,1)
```

This will give you the "Final" rankings. There won't be any ties because of the tiny decimals we added in the previous formula. The results end up looking just like your sample.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm not familiar with array, it worked but I'm not fully understanding what the array does I'll have to read up on it, but I can confirm this worked, and I'm glad I asked it out right because I was not going to get this on my own nor was I having any luck googling it. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Array formulas just let you perform a test multiple times in one line, so in the example above when it gets to the second row (C3) Excel is asking *all* of the following questions: A2 = A3?, A3 = A3?, A4 = A3?, A5 = A3?, A6 = A3?. Which converts to `FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE`. And then, because it's nested inside an IF formula, it returns the corresponding value in column B for each TRUE value, and an arbitrarily huge number for each FALSE: `9999999999, 2, 9999999999, 7, 199`. Finally the SMALL function picks the smallest number out of that array (which is 2), then we add the decimal.

Comment: You could just as easily use `MIN` instead of `SMALL`: `=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$6=A2,$B$2:$B$6,9999999999))+(B2*0.000000001)`. But `SMALL` is fun because you can ask it to return the *n*th smallest number.